# How to get firstname from using this query?

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to fetch firstname from employeedetail table where the character string of firstname = 5, I am executing below code :

```
select firstname=(case when len(firstname) = 5 then firstname end) from employeedetail
```

it gives me what i want, but it giving me the null values as well, just because of character string value. Now i don't want these null values in my output. How can i do this?

Answer (score 3):

Add `where len(firstname) = 5` to your query.

This will help you avoid all rows where length of firstname column data is not 5 characters altogether.

Your problem arose as `CASE` statement did not have the `ELSE` part defined which resulted in `NULL` for all those case whose `WHEN` part was false.

If you want to handle the cases where firstname is longer or shorter than 5 characters another way, just add more `when` clauses to your `case` statement.

Comment: I Just missed by seconds from posting the answer. Anyways good catch +1

Comment: I'm surprised I got my answer in first. :-)

Comment: but one question in my mind is how can i eliminate null values in other way? as per your solution we are using `where` clause. but what if i want to work on null values without using the above condition.

Comment: The null values occur because your `case` statement evaluates to `null` when `len(firstname) <> 5`. My where clause eliminates those rows.  I'm not sure what you mean by "work on null values", so Im not sure what to suggest.

Comment: what condition do i need to apply in case statement, for those values which character value is  < or > 5

Comment: i am running `select firstname=(case when len(firstname) = 5 then firstname end) from employeedetail where firstname is not null` and getting two records according to my table. but can't eliminate the nulls according to this query

Answer (score 1):

```
select firstname=(case when ISNULL(firstname,'')<>'' AND len(firstname) = 5 then firstname end) from employeedetail
```